# firejail problem with private-etc

Tags: command-line, bash, virtualbox, java

I want to sandbox a java program with `firejail` and use the option `--private-etc=` so the command i use looks like this:

```
firejail --private-etc=none java -jar ...
```

But if i add that option it throws the error:

```
/bin/bash: java: command not found
```

I know that i need to add the required files to `--private-etc=` instead of `none` and that is the question, which files I have to add so it recognizes the command `java`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Allow programs to access /etc/alternatives, i.e. use `--private-etc=alternatives`

---

Long answer (maybe helpful for other "command not found" errors): Find out, which binary is actually executed

```
$ whereis javac
javac: /usr/bin/javac /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1.gz
$ ls -l /usr/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 /usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac
```

And here we have the culprit: `/etc/alternatives`